# How to optimize socket io performance?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have set up a server for a real time chat (single, group). The clients send their data in a certain interval to the server. The server sends data to the other users, also in a certain interval, to the clients.

If I add more users into chat, the performance gets worse. How can I improve the performance now?

Can I create a more stable performance by using a bigger interval?

Or do you have other ideas?

And is there a debugging tool to check which server actions slow the server down?

Is socket.io support lots of users for chat?

I am using `socket.io 2.x`.

Comment: What do you mean by "sending data in a certain interval"? Are you pooling the data at the client-side somehow? How much data are you talking about? How long is the interval now?

Comment: @EriksKlotins This is simple chat app. App team send us text, image, audio, video, contact and location text. I have stored this in our DB and send to other users who are connected in that chat. It takes around 20-30 seconds to send data to other users.

Comment: You did not really answer my question. Are you deliberately pooling the data? What is the size of the payload? Have you profiled what takes the most time?

Comment: @EriksKlotins I haven't profiled the data. How can i profiled the data?
Payload size around roughly 5 bytes.I am not deliberately pooling the data.

Comment: I'm aware that you want to receive an answered aimed specifically towards Socket.io, but I would strongly recommend against using it in the first place.
Socket.io is elegant but very slow. And since native Websocket (Or even better - uWebsockets.js) is already widely supported then there isn't really any justification for using Socket.io.

Comment: Thanks @DanielShlomo. Can you please help me about uWebsockets.js? So, I can replace my socket.io code to websocket code.

Comment: @RakeshSingh Sure, In the GitHub repo they have quite a few examples of how to use it. (Pub/Sub: https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets.js/blob/master/examples/WebSockets.js , Simple example: https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets.js/blob/master/examples/WebSockets.js ). It's almost a drop-in replacement for the WS module. It's also suppose to replace Express (which is also painfully slow) if you want, but it can run along side Express.

Comment: @RakeshSingh In the browser you can just use the native Websocket API ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on the discussion in comments, there is not enough information to suggest anything else than to investigate the issue further.

1. Sending 5 bytes of data  (really??)  even to thousands of users should not clog the network. However, this boils down to implementation details. Perhaps you reestablish the socket connection with every message sent. Perhaps you block the thread with sending the messages. Or something like that happens
2. You mention a database. Have you looked into that? Perhaps the database is the bottleneck.

You can read up this post on [how to implement time profiling for nodeJS](https://medium.com/better-programming/time-profiling-in-node-js-7f82a95d6a9a). Other than that, try implementing a simple script that isolates the problem. e.g.

1. Measure how long it takes to send a simple message to a large number users. Does time increases significantly with more users/longer messages?
2. Measure how long it takes to look up related stuff in the database

Post relevant code here and ask for second pair of eyes to check for issues.

Comment: In addition to Eriks Klotins's recommendations, here are a few queries/pointers:

1. You mention node JS. How are you handling the client requests and sending the updates to them?
2. Are you using 'cluster' and/or 'worker-threads' modules to distribute the work, maximize use of available resources (CPU cores/memory/IO)?
3. Are you blocking the main node JS event loop with any synchronous calls? For instance: is your db update happening in the main thread/node event loop instead of a worker-thread. Same for your update push notifcations to clients.

Answer (score 2):

**Use Socket.io’s Binary Mode**
Socket.io provides an end-to-end ‘binary mode’ for the WebSockets transport (and a good-enough variant for XHR Polling). All that’s needed to trigger binary mode is the use of Buffers.

Comment: Can you please provide me example of binary mode?